# Flutter Reactive State

Tags: flutter, dart, reactive, flutter-getx

I define a model reactively with GetX and send this model reactively to the view with the help of StateMixin. But this variable I sent changes the main variable as well. How exactly does this happen and how can I fix it? In the example I gave below, when I change the id value, the id automatically changes in the rawMyModel model. But I don't want it to change.

detail_controller.dart

```
class DetailController extends GetxController with StateMixin<Rx<MyModel>> {
  late final MyModel rawMyModel;

  @override
  void onInit() async {
    super.onInit();
    rawMyModel = (Get.arguments as MyModel);
    change(Rx(rawMyModel), status: RxStatus.success());
  }

  void reset() {
    change(Rx(rawMyModel), status: RxStatus.success());
  }
}
```

detail_page.dart

```
class DetailPage extends GetView<DetailController> {
  const DetailPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: controller.obx((Rx<MyModel>? myModel) => _buildBody(myModel: myModel!)),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody({required Rx<MyModel> myModel}) {
    print(myModel.value.toString());
    myModel.update((val) => val.id = 5); // change
   }
}
```

Comment: you are passing the `rawMyModel` to it, so what do you expect? They are the same object.

Comment: Actually, my thought here is that I pass it as a parameter to the Rx class, so I think it transforms it into a different object. For example, when I have more than one MyModel class and assign a common number variable to them, the number variable in all classes does not change. Because now MyModel is its own value.